# App does not seem to be compatible with any device

Tags: android, file, manifest

I know this question has been asked many times. But all the posts in this forum do not help me so far. Please assist with this, my app does not seem to be compatible with any device. I have included a picture and my manifest file for clarity

[image: Android play Store screenshot]

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="za.co.coolnot.miim" >
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"

        />   


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".Miim"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/miim"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/White" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".SelectPages"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_select_pages" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Error"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_error" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace compile **'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'** from build.gradle (app level)

with compile **'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'**

Comment: Put the answer here, don't just paste a link, that link may die.

Answer (score 0):

Use < compatible-screens > instead, [as explained here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html):

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

...because:

> Although you can also use the < compatible-screens > element for the
>   reverse scenario (when your application is not compatible with smaller
>   screens), it's easier if you instead use the < supports-screens > as
>   discussed in the next section, because it doesn't require you to
>   specify each screen density your application supports.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that and the issue still continues.